# Postgres is not accepting commands and Vacuum failed due to missing chunk number error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, data-corruption

Version: 9.4.4

```
Exception while inserting a record in health_status.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database "db"
Hint: Stop the postmaster and vacuum that database in single-user mode.
```

As indicated in the above error, I tried logging to single-user mode and tried to run full vacuum but instead received below error:

```
PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.4.4
backend> vacuum full;
< 2019-11-06 14:26:25.179 UTC > WARNING:  database "db" must be vacuumed within 999999 transactions
< 2019-11-06 14:26:25.179 UTC > HINT:  To avoid a database shutdown, execute a database-wide VACUUM in that database.
    You might also need to commit or roll back old prepared transactions.
< 2019-11-06 14:26:25.215 UTC > ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value xxxx in pg_toast_1234
< 2019-11-06 14:26:25.215 UTC > STATEMENT:  vacuum full;
```

I tried to run `vacuum` but the same is leading to another error that indicates missing attributes for relid xxxxx

```
backend> vacuum;
< 2019-11-06 14:27:47.556 UTC > ERROR:  catalog is missing 3 attribute(s) for relid xxxxx
< 2019-11-06 14:27:47.556 UTC > STATEMENT:  vacuum;
```

I tried to do a `vacuum freeze` for the entire db but it is leading to the catalog error again after waiting for sometime.

Furthermore, I tried to run `vacuum freeze` for a single table which was working fine but when I do the vacuuming for all tables, it probably includes the corrupted one as well and ends up with the same error:

```
backend> vacuum full freeze
< 2019-11-07 08:54:25.958 UTC > WARNING:  database "db" must be vacuumed within 999987 transactions
< 2019-11-07 08:54:25.958 UTC > HINT:  To avoid a database shutdown, execute a database-wide VACUUM in that database.
    You might also need to commit or roll back old prepared transactions.
< 2019-11-07 08:54:26.618 UTC > ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value xxxxx in pg_toast_xxxx
< 2019-11-07 08:54:26.618 UTC > STATEMENT:  vacuum full freeze
```

Is there a way to figure out the corrupted table and a way to restore the integrity of the database so the application can access the rest of the database?

P.S. I do not have a backup to restore the data so deleting the corrupted data or somehow fixing it would be the only solution here.

Comment: Have you identified to which table the toast object "pg_toast_1234" belongs to?

Comment: Hi Laurenz, Thank you for the response. Yes, I have, using regclass and have also dropped that table, post which the missing chunk issue disappeared. However, we are unable to work on "catalog is missing 3 attribute(s) for relid xxxxx", due to which vacuuming is still not happening.